# Does anyone know of a working color picker plugin for Expression Engine 2.x?

Tags: fieldtype, jquery

I've found all the plugins on devot-ee.com, but none of them seem to work. Most of them seem to cause some sort of javascript conflict. The "modal" that the pickers use show up at the bottom of the publish form and the picker fields don't work.

I'm using EE 2.7.3.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like.

http://cl.ly/image/2t3f1W3j153k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the issues are. The plugins simply haven't been updated for the most recent versions of EE.

I use a different locations for my third_party folder. The url in most of these plugins look for the theme directory in the default location using this url:

```
$this->EE->config->item('theme_folder_url').'third_party/plugin_folder_name
```

But, there's also a config variable avaialable for getting the defined third_party theme directory:

```
$this->EE->config->item('url_third_themes').'/plugin_folder_name
```

So, in any of these color picker plugins, just open the PHP file that comes with them and update the url to the theme files.

You can find a list of hidden EE config variables here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html